# python logging: multiple loggers error

Tags: python, logging

I have objects called Job which has it's own logger (each Job need to have a log file which is represented by logging.getLogger())

The problem is I create thousands of Jobs (~4000) and they all want to create a logger.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u/lib/btool/Job.py", line 151, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 936, in _open
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/x/zooland/20160710-032802.log'
```

Is there way to deal with multiple loggers?

Comment: A different logger file for each object seems to be an overkill to me. Can you not log by class names or types or something?

Comment: each job has a directory of its own and log file needs to be there. can a single logger write to different log files? but that still doesnt address the issue of the need to open thousands of log files, correct?

Comment: I do not know if the default `FileHandler` keeps the file object open. If it does, then another idea would be write your custom file handler which opens the file, appends the message and then closes the file.

Comment: or maybe only open when you need to write to it. does logging leaves the log file open?

Comment: yes i used to have a custom file handler that does that. i wanted to try logging as it is more widely used. but i guess it cant?

Comment: You can use logging. You just need a custom handler written for it. Let me post an answer with samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom file handler that stores the log message and then closes the file.

```
import logging


class MyFileHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        super().__init__()

    def emit(self, record):
        log_text = self.format(record)
        try:
            fh = open(self.filename, "a")
            fh.write(log_text)
            fh.close()

            return True
        except:
            return False


logger = logging.getLogger("job")

handler = MyFileHandler("file-1")
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.error("hola")
```

Comment: super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Comment: do i have to pass something to super().__init__() ?

Comment: I am using Python 3. Are you on Python 2? In that case please follow the correct syntax.

Comment: not sure the difference but would it better to extend logging.FileHandler instead of logging.Handler?

Comment: If you extend `FileHandler` then you inherit the same behavior. It would have been more complex. For Python 2.7, use `super(MyFileHandler, self).__init__()`